# Debian tcsh not respecting locale for character class expansion

Tags: debian, wildcards, posix, locale, tcsh

Using Debian 11, tcsh version

```
tcsh 6.21.00 (Astron) 2019-05-08 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,nd,color,filec
```

In a directory with two files, `a` and `A`,

```
$ echo [a-z]  
a A
```

This is an unexpected change from just expanding to `a`. I expect this behavior to be locale-dependent, and with tcsh built with `wide` and `nls` options it should be respecting locale settings AIUI - but changing `LC_ALL` to `C` rather than `en_US.UTF-8` does not change it.

At some point in the recent past (more recently than my Debian 11 upgrade, which was several months ago), something must have changed to affect collation behavior. Half an hour of poking through man pages and related documentation isn't turning up anything useful. Only tcsh and csh are suffering this behavior, not bash/dash/sh.

While I get that for portability one should use POSIX character classes, I'm not concerned about portability for purposes of this question. I just want to determine how to restore the ASCII collation behavior I'm used to.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's a locale issue. `[a-c]` matches on all of 0-9 A-Z a-c for me. Looks more like a bug. But why would you be using tcsh in this century?

Answer (score 3):

Update: this does appear to be a bug in tcsh. I built the latest tcsh 6.23.00 from scratch and character classes work as expected. [Reported to Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=950938), was already fixed upstreams at https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/commit/4679bde3e1ceca63d6eb4de5ce41c996405e61aa as [indicated on the mailing  list](https://mailman.astron.com/pipermail/tcsh/2019-November/000039.html)